# How do I get an actual document set name to appear in Enterprise Search results in SP2010?

Tags: search-results, document-set, enterprise-search

We have Enterprise Search running on SP2010 and when I search for a term that is in the metadata or even title of a document set.

The current search results simply list "Document Set" instead of the actual name of the document set, which is "RFP for Paving Contract."  -Thanks

Comment: Have the same issue for one of the Content Types